# How to escape an input string in Bash

Tags: bash, escape-characters, command-substitution, json

I'm using the jq tool to handle some JSON in bash.
Just one problem, while using this line:

```
PB_ACL="acl="`echo $IMGREQ | jq -r'.data.acl'`
```

Result:

```
echo $PB_ACL      // acl=
```

The expected value jq has to filter out is: "acl":"public-read"
But it's not working now. I think it has to to with the dash (-) symbol.

How do I escape such incoming string data?

Comment: Try `PB_ACL="acl=$(echo $IMGREQ | jq -r'.data.acl')"` (Or use the backticks, just leave it inside the double quotes)

Comment: The command between the backticks  to be processed. (Command Substitution) So Im afraid this ain't gonna work...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment but command substitution do occur inside double quotes.

Comment: Just getting:    acl=echo

Comment: Are you sure you modified your code with the change I made?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I just found the error... Missed a space after the -r...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25474/discussion-between-milkmannetje-and-user43791).

Comment: Sorry, no chat possibility for me : blocked by the firewall...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed a space:

```
PB_ACL="acl="`echo $IMGREQ | jq -r '.data.acl'`
                                  ^
```